# Как спарсить большой массив после ответа json

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api

Посылаю get запрос google api.

```
$request_params = array('origin' => A,
                        'destination' => B,
                        'key' => token);
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?'.$get_params));
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

В ответ приходит это:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"geocoded_waypoints" : [
 {
    "geocoder_status" : "OK",
    "place_id" : "ChIJ7cv00DwsDogRAMDACa2m4K8",
    "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
 },
 {
    "geocoder_status" : "OK",
    "place_id" : "ChIJ69Pk6jdlyIcRDqM1KDY3Fpg",
    "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
 },
 {
    "geocoder_status" : "OK",
    "place_id" : "ChIJgdL4flSKrYcRnTpP0XQSojM",
    "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
 },
 {
    "geocoder_status" : "OK",
    "place_id" : "ChIJE9on3F3HwoAR9AhGJW_fL-I",
    "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
 }
],
"routes": [ {
"summary": "I-40 W",
"legs": [ {
  "steps": [ {
    "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
    "start_location": {
      "lat": 41.8507300,
      "lng": -87.6512600
    },
    "end_location": {
      "lat": 41.8525800,
      "lng": -87.6514100
    },
    "polyline": {
      "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
    },
    "duration": {
      "value": 19,
      "text": "1 min"
    },
    "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
    "distance": {
      "value": 207,
      "text": "0.1 mi"
    }
  },
  ...
  ... additional steps of this leg
...
... additional legs of this route
  "duration": {
    "value": 74384,
    "text": "20 hours 40 mins"
  },
  "distance": {
    "value": 2137146,
    "text": "1,328 mi"
  },
  "start_location": {
    "lat": 35.4675602,
    "lng": -97.5164276
  },
  "end_location": {
    "lat": 34.0522342,
    "lng": -118.2436849
  },
  "start_address": "Oklahoma City, OK, USA",
  "end_address": "Los Angeles, CA, USA"
} ],
"copyrights": "Map data ©2010 Google, Sanborn",
"overview_polyline": {
  "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOnzh@vlbBtc~@tsE`vnApw{A`dw@~w\\|tNtqf@l{Yd_Fblh@rxo@b}@xxSfytAblk@xxaBeJxlcBb~t@zbh@jc|Bx}C`rv@rw|@rlhA~dVzeo@vrSnc}Axf]fjz@xfFbw~@dz{A~d{A|zOxbrBbdUvpo@`cFp~xBc`Hk@nurDznmFfwMbwz@bbl@lq~@loPpxq@bw_@v|{CbtY~jGqeMb{iF|n\\~mbDzeVh_Wr|Efc\\x`Ij{kE}mAb~uF{cNd}xBjp]fulBiwJpgg@|kHntyArpb@bijCk_Kv~eGyqTj_|@`uV`k|DcsNdwxAott@r}q@_gc@nu`CnvHx`k@dse@j|p@zpiAp|gEicy@`omFvaErfo@igQxnlApqGze~AsyRzrjAb__@ftyB}pIlo_BflmA~yQftNboWzoAlzp@mz`@|}_@fda@jakEitAn{fB_a]lexClshBtmqAdmY_hLxiZd~XtaBndgC"
},
"warnings": [ ],
"waypoint_order": [ 0, 1 ],
"bounds": {
  "southwest": {
    "lat": 34.0523600,
    "lng": -118.2435600
  },
  "northeast": {
    "lat": 41.8781100,
    "lng": -87.6297900
  }
 }
} ]
}
```

Как, например, обратиться к этому участку кода? Нужно извлечь переменную value.

```
"duration": {
  "value": 19,
  "text": "1 min"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш `json`-файл представляет набор пар ключ-значение, либо массивов, вот соответственно по индексами строковым или числовым и обращаться следует.

В вашем пути до искомого `value` необходимо обратиться к полю `routes` (массив), потом `legs` (массив), его нулевому элементу, в нем `steps` (тоже массив), еще раз к нулевому элементу, а потом `duration` и `value`.

```
$result->routes[0]->legs[0]->steps[0]->duration->value;
```